# Current Sense Amplifier Error when using negative voltage

Tags: amplifier, simulation, current-measurement

I'm using an INA210 current sense amplifier. It works when the voltage source V1 is positive in the below image. But when it is negative, something weird happens.

Positive voltage case:

[image]

Negative voltage case:

[image]

So, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So it will not work if the common mode range is -5V.

Solution: use a current sense amp that accepts -5V to +5V common mode, or put the shunt on the ground side of the load so the common mode is close to 0V.

Comment: Ohh so this is the CM range they meant. So I should find one that covers the range I need. At first is what in the low side and was working but I need it high side so now all is clear. Thanks

Comment: I have tried the INA271 which has a CMR of -16 to 80 V. In the simulation the output voltage is not changing. Do you know what would be the problem?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uxv1sfPQKluuXZnkt0oFCk5AMXv1ldsO/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N9y_0Keoe4RU3nSAlpbE7XuVqmRz6c6S/view?usp=sharing
datasheet:https://www.ti.com/product/INA271

Comment: don't ground bufin pin, just connect to preout

Comment: Did that, now the voltage changes across the preout. But how to interpret this change? I mean how to know calculate the current using the output voltage? I didn't understand the equations in the datahseet

Comment: It says it has a gain of 14 or 20 depending on which chip you get so you should get an output voltage equal to 12x or 20x the voltage drop on your sense resistor. This chip only takes one polarity of input voltage though, so if you expect current to go in both direction it's no good

Comment: I want to build a current sense circuit to measure a current that changes from 1 mA to 1A (both directions). So, can someone recommend any current sense amp that could help me do that.

Comment: What is the range of common mode voltage?

Comment: My sources are +-22V

Comment: You should use something as this https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina148.pdf?ts=1661000116225&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Thanks will try it. But it seems that there is no gain. So, if my shunt is 0.025 ohm and 1 A is flowing, then the voltage drop is 0.025V which is the voltage at the output of the INA148. Is that correct?

Comment: Why not put the current sense resistor on the ground side of the load?

Comment: That would solve the problem but due to my circuit, it is not possible. The load is a kind of electrochemical electrodes. Thus, the current sense should be above the load.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/product/LMP8602-Q1 maxes out at -22V. If the voltage is delivered by an amplifier, and you put the sense resistor in the feedback loop, you can increase the resistor value to get a higher voltage to measure without having a voltage drop on your electrodes.

Comment: You could also use [INA103](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina103.pdf), at its maximum +/-25V supply the datasheet says it will handle +/-22V common mode if the output voltage is low (so you can't use much gain).

Comment: Didnt get it much. So I can get a gain if the supply is +- 22V?